# Bit twiddling in C: how to convert from 2^N to N?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

What is a good bit-twiddling routine to convert a number in the range [2^N,2^(N-1)-1] to N?

Some examples:

- f(1) -> 0
- f([2-3]) -> 1
- f([4-7]) -> 2
- f([8-15]) -> 3

Here is one implementation:

```
uint f(uint num)
{
    for (uint shifts = 0; num; shifts++) 
        num >>= 1;
    return (shifts - 1);
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get lg2 of a number that is 2^k](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213825/how-to-get-lg2-of-a-number-that-is-2k)

Comment: do you mean "range [2^N-1, 2^(N-1)]"?

Comment: I'd guess `[2^N,2^(N+1)-1]` is the more appropriate range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how wide your data-type is, and how much memory you have available, a lookup-table is one possibility.  It's almost certainly the fastest approach.

For other approaches, see http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious, and the subsequent sections.

Answer (score 3):

As most general approach, binary search may help. For values 0..31 it need only 5 stages.

```
y = 0;
if(x >= 0x10000<<y) y += 0x10;
if(x >= 0x100<<y) y += 0x08;
if(x >= 0x10<<y) y += 0x04;
if(x >= 0x4<<y) y += 0x02;
if(x >= 0x2<<y) y += 0x01;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at hacks for computing base 2 logarithm (or leading zero count, they are the same) on this page: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

You could also find useful the function `__builtin_clz` (or `_BitScanReverse` for VS) for x86.